# Microphone with a very short pause is sending message to the bot

Tags: botframework, speech-to-text, web-chat

I am using Cognetive Speech services from botframework to add speech-to-text ability for our bot. everything is but the problem is that as soon as the user makes a very short pause, silence is detected and recognition result is sent.

I want to know if there is any config that I can use to set the microphone on/off or atleast wait until the user sends the text to the bot